LWC mass action button on a standard records list page
I'm trying to create a LWC button that will be used as action (delete selected) on standard record listing page:

Now, I know that LWC can receive object and record contexts in a conventional @api properties, but how do I get a context with a "list of selected records", is this even possible?

Consider making a flow-based action. The selections are passed to a text collection available for input called "ids". You can then put the LWC in a flow screen, if you make it available there.

+1 to Phil's point. AFAIK there is no choice but to use flows at the moment.

Seems this is currently impossible even with custom lightning pages, which is really frustrating. Here's the related idea report
Considering it's dated 2020 it really leaves a bad impression of a dead platform.

The usual joke is that it takes 10 years for Salesforce to deliver on stuff from the IdeaExchange. Being a bit more charitable though, crowdsourcing is just really hard to manage at Salesforce's scale (contradicting ideas, a lot of rubbish to wade through, can't break existing functionality, can't give people too much of a glimpse into the secret sauce, etc..)
